# Can I skip screens after catching a pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

After catching a wild pokemon, there are many screens/messages I have to click through:

1. "All right... you caught" message
2. Multiplier + catch rewards screen
3. Exp gain screen
4. Pokemon info screen
5. "You tucked xyz away" message

Is there anything I can do to skip past these? A huge amount of the time it takes to catch pokemon is wasted on these screens.

Similarly, when I feed candy to my pokemon, it takes three clicks per candy and I can only feed a single candy at a time. Is there any way to speed this process up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot skip these screens. However, you can hold down ok/cancel in order for the text to appear more quickly as it is being "written" in the various screens/dialog boxes. Personally, I just hold down the shoulder button so the text scrolls as fast as possible and spam A or B to bypass the user input needed to move to the next screen/dialog.

As for speeding up feeding candies to Pokemon, the only way to really optimize it is to feed it species-specific candies. Species candy will add 1 AV to all stats, as opposed to say, mighty candy only adding 1 value to attack. Additionally, there's no X/XL mechanism where you need to feed multiple candies at higher levels. Feeding your Onix of any level 1 Onix candy will increase all of it's AV values by 1 up to the 200 value cap.

Comment: For the 2nd part, I believe the OP asking about feeding candy to increase AVs rather than feeding a berry to their partner. But the answer is pretty much the same - nothing really can be done to speed up the process

Comment: Wondercricket is correct, I meant e.g. Mighty Candy or species-specific candies. 600 clicks to feed 200 Gastly Candies feels like an insane oversight, but also I can totally believe that the devs didn't think people would actually bother doing it.

Comment: @BenP. Yup, I've updated it with the only optimization I could think of. The only way to save button presses is to stick to species-specific candy.

Comment: Bummer. I recently started doing the Cerulean Cave 2F Chansey farming method and the post-capture screens sometimes take _minutes_ to get through when you catch a 90k exp Chansey and you get 15+ level-up messages for multiple pokemon.